# MPI Communications problem for simple sorting algorithm

Tags: mpi, race-condition

I have a question about testing for completion for a simple parallel sorting algorithm. The sorting algorithm isn't meant to be the most efficient, it's just a proxy for a more complex problem. The question concerns how to handle termination of a parallel sorting algorithm. In short, the code below has every process get a set of initial random numbers, and the goal is to generate a complete sorted list of all the numbers across all processes. To do this, each process is assigned a range of values to process, e.g. 4 processes with numbers in the range 0-99 would have each process handle a range of 25 values according to rank. If a number is out of range, the value is passed either left or right according to whether it is below or above its assigned range. Each process then proceeds to sort its current list while monitoring, via MPI_Iprobe, for any possible values it receives from its neighbors.

Here's the important bit. When a process is done sorting, it sends a "done" message to each other process, but it continues to monitor communications in case a late-coming number arrives or to receive "done" messages. If a new value arrives, then it sends an "undone" message to say that it is no longer finished and then proceeds to sort the new value. When a "done" message is received from every process, then it stores the results and terminates.

My concern is that it may be possible to have a race condition where process 100 reports it's done and then subsequently receives a value from process 101 causing it to send the undone message. But before it can send the undone message all the other processes, which have received the original done message may terminate before receiving the undone message. So how can I check whether there are any pending messages remaining across all processes? Is there a different strategy I should be using?  The algorithm here works fine on a small number of processes, but for the more complex problem I am seeing done/undone pairs getting left behind.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

void swap(int* i, int* j)
{
  int temp = *i;
  *i = *j;
  *j = temp;
}

void printlist(int rank, FILE* output, int* list, int i, int len);

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{

  MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

  int rank, size;

  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

  int N = atoi(argv[1]);
  long int seed;
  if (argc > 2) 
    seed = atol(argv[2])+rank;
  else {
    if (rank==0) 
      seed = (long int)time(NULL);
    MPI_Bcast(&seed, 1, MPI_LONG, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    seed += rank;
  }
  srandom(seed);

  char fname[256];
  sprintf(fname, "proc-%d.out", rank);
  FILE* output = fopen(fname, "w");

  int* list = (int*)malloc(size*N*sizeof(int));
  int i;
  for (i=0; i<N; ++i)
    list[i] = random()%1000;
  int len = N;

  int rmsg = 0, smsg;
  if (rank > 0)
    MPI_Recv(&rmsg, 1, MPI_INT, rank-1, 3, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);

  if (rank == 0) 
    printf("Before:\n");
  fprintf(output,"Before:\n");
  for (i=0; i<N; ++i) {
    printf("Rank %d: %4d\n", rank, list[i]);
    fprintf(output,"Rank %d: %4d\n", rank, list[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");
  fprintf(output,"\n");

  if (rank < size-1)
    MPI_Send(&rmsg, 1, MPI_INT, rank+1, 3, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

  MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);


  i = 0;
  int j, k=0;
  //  MPI_Status status[100];
  MPI_Status status;
  MPI_Request rrqst = MPI_REQUEST_NULL;
  MPI_Request srqst[100];
  for (j=0; j<100; ++j)
    srqst[j] = MPI_REQUEST_NULL;
  int buffer[100];
  int index;
  int buffcnt = 0;
  int done[size], alldone=0;
  for (j=0; j<size; ++j) done[j] = 0;
  
  double start = MPI_Wtime();
 
  while (!alldone) {
    int msg_ready;
    fprintf(output, "Rank %d %e: have more work to do...\n", rank, MPI_Wtime()-start);
    MPI_Iprobe(MPI_ANY_SOURCE, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &msg_ready, &status);
    if (msg_ready) {
      switch(status.MPI_TAG) {
      case 0:
    MPI_Recv(&rmsg, 1, MPI_INT, status.MPI_SOURCE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
    fprintf(output,"Rank %d %e: received %d from %d\n", rank, MPI_Wtime()-start,
        rmsg, status.MPI_SOURCE);
    if (i >= len) {
      done[rank] = 0;
      fprintf(output,"Rank %d %e: set smsg to %d\n", rank, MPI_Wtime()-start, smsg);
      for (j=0; j<size; ++j) {
        if (j != rank) {
          buffer[buffcnt] = -(rank+1);
          fprintf(output, "Rank %d %e: send undone message to %d\n", rank, MPI_Wtime()-start, j);
          MPI_Send(&buffer[buffcnt], 1, MPI_INT, j, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
          ++buffcnt;
        }
      }
    }
    list[len++] = rmsg;
    break;
      case 1:
    MPI_Recv(&rmsg, 1, MPI_INT, status.MPI_SOURCE, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
    fprintf(output,"Rank %d %e: received %s message from %d\n", rank, MPI_Wtime()-start,
        (rmsg > 0 ? "done" : "undone"), status.MPI_SOURCE);
    if (rmsg > 0) {
      done[status.MPI_SOURCE] = 1;
      alldone = 1;
      for (j=0; j<size && alldone; ++j)
        alldone = done[j];
      fprintf(output, "Rank %d %e: Alldone = %d\n", rank, MPI_Wtime()-start, alldone);
    } else {
      done[status.MPI_SOURCE] = 0;
      alldone = 0;
    }
    break;
      default:
    break;
      }
    } else {
      if (i < len) {
    if (list[i] < rank*(1000/size)) {
      fprintf(output,"Rank %d %e: Sending %d to %d\n", rank, MPI_Wtime()-start,
          list[i], (rank+size-1)%size);
      buffer[buffcnt] = list[i];
      fprintf(output,"Rank %d %e: set smsg to %d\n", rank, MPI_Wtime()-start, buffer[buffcnt]);
      list[i] = list[--len];
      if (i>0) --i;
      MPI_Send(&buffer[buffcnt], 1, MPI_INT, (rank+size-1)%size, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
      fprintf(output,"Rank %d %e: Sent %d to %d\n", rank, MPI_Wtime()-start,
          buffer[buffcnt], (rank+size-1)%size);
      ++buffcnt;
    } else if (list[i] >= (rank+1)*(1000/size)) {
      fprintf(output,"Rank %d %e: Sending %d to %d\n", rank, MPI_Wtime()-start,
          list[i], (rank+1)%size);
      buffer[buffcnt] = list[i];
      fprintf(output,"Rank %d %e: set smsg to %d\n", rank, MPI_Wtime()-start, buffer[buffcnt]);
      list[i] = list[--len];
      if (i>0) --i;
      MPI_Send(&buffer[buffcnt], 1, MPI_INT, (rank+1)%size, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
      fprintf(output,"Rank %d %e: Sent %d to %d\n", rank, MPI_Wtime()-start,
          smsg, (rank+1)%size);
      ++buffcnt;
    } else {      
      if (i>0 && list[i] < list[i-1]) {
        fprintf(output,"Rank %d %e: Swap %d and %d\n", rank, MPI_Wtime()-start,
            list[i], list[i-1]);
        swap(&list[i-1], &list[i]);
        --i;
      } else {
        if (i==len-1 || list[i] <= list[i+1]) {
          ++i;
        } else {
          fprintf(output,"Rank %d %e: Swap %d and %d\n", rank, MPI_Wtime()-start,
              list[i], list[i+1]);
          swap(&list[i], &list[i+1]);
        }
      }
    }
      } else {
    fprintf(output,"Rank %d %e: set smsg to %d\n", rank, MPI_Wtime()-start, buffer[buffcnt]);
    if (done[rank] == 0) {
      for (j=0; j<size; ++j)
        if (j != rank) {
          buffer[buffcnt] = rank+1;
          fprintf(output,"Rank %d %e: Sending done to %d\n", rank, MPI_Wtime()-start, j);
          MPI_Send(&buffer[buffcnt], 1, MPI_INT, j, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
          ++buffcnt;
        }
      done[rank] = 1;
      alldone = 1;
      for (j=0; j<size && alldone; ++j)
        alldone = done[j];
      fprintf(output, "Rank %d %e: Alldone = %d\n", rank, MPI_Wtime()-start, alldone);
    }
      }
    }
    fprintf(output,"Rank %d %e: done = (", rank, MPI_Wtime()-start);
    for (j=0; j<size-1; ++j)
      fprintf(output,"%d, ", done[j]);
    fprintf(output,"%d)\n", done[size-1]);
    if (!done[rank] || alldone) {
      printlist(rank, output, list, i, len);
    }
    fflush(output);
  }

  MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

  fprintf(output,"Rank %d %e: ready for final print\n", rank, MPI_Wtime()-start);

  smsg = rank;
  fprintf(output,"Rank %d %e: set smsg to %d\n", rank, MPI_Wtime()-start, smsg);
  if (rank > 0) {
    MPI_Recv(&j, 1, MPI_INT, rank-1, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
  }

  if (rank == 0) {
    j = 0;
    printf("\nAfter:\n");
  }
  fprintf(output,"\nAfter:\n");
  for (i=0; i<len; ++i) {
    printf("Rank %d #%d: %4d\n", rank, i+j, list[i]);
    fprintf(output,"Rank %d #%d: %4d\n", rank, i+j, list[i]);
  }

  if (rank < size-1) {
    rmsg = j+len;
    MPI_Send(&rmsg, 1, MPI_INT, rank+1, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  }

  fclose(output);
  
  MPI_Finalize();
  return 0;
}
  
void printlist(int rank, FILE* output, int* list, int j, int len)
{
  int i;
  //  printf("\n");
  fprintf(output,"\n");
  for (i=0; i<len; ++i) {
    //    printf("Rank %d: list[%d] = %d %s\n", rank, i, list[i], (i==j ? "<<<" : ""));
    fprintf(output,"Rank %d: list[%d] = %d %s\n", rank, i, list[i], (i==j ? "<<<" : ""));
  }
  //  printf("\n");
  fprintf(output,"\n");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your approach is that a process may send without the receiver knowing that something is coming. Probing works for seeing if something is coming in, but how do you decide to stop probing?

For this sort of situation the non-blocking barrier was invented: each process sends its messages, posts the barrier, and then alternates between probing and testing the barrier. If the barrier completes, you know that you've received all incoming messages.

This strategy is older than the introduction of MPI_Barrier: it is known as "distributed termination detection". How can you draw a global conclusion based on local tests.

Comment: This makes sense now that I've poked around a little with that phrase. Not sure I completely understand your description of how the non-blocking barrier works yet, can you point me to an example?

Comment: https://theartofhpc.com/pcse/mpi-collective.html#Nonblockingbarrier

Comment: That example is helpful, I'm starting to understand. But some places I've read that once the barrier is entered, I can't do any more sends or risk a race condition (equivalent to my "undone" message I was using where I have to hope that message reaches at least one other process before they all decide they're done). My problem though, has a situation where a received message may potentially trigger a send, and that message could be received after I hit the barrier. So if a message is received after I've hit the barrier, I could be in trouble. I assume there isn't a way to cancel the barrier.